# Go to a named range based on a cell entry without editing the macro

Tags: excel, excel-2010

I have an entry in cell O3. (Excel 2010) Based on that entry I would like my macro to go to the named range in that cell without having to edit the macro.

For example:
Cell O3 has "Mon" in it and I want the macro to go to named range "Mon" on the sheet. (It's huge.)

My macro has the code

```
Application.Goto Reference:="Mon"
```

If I want to see time sheet info for "Thu" (for thursday) all I'd have to do is type in "Thu" in the cell O3, run the macro and it would take me to the named range "Thu" in the sheet.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
Application.Goto Range("O3").Value
```

Or

```
Sub Demo()
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim str As String
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Set sw = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2") 'change sheet name as required
    str = sw.Range("O3")

    Set rng = Range(str)
    rng.Parent.Select
    rng.Select
End Sub
```

Got this from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23251553/6075259).